# android.R.id view binding in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I've got layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`
where is a `TextView` with id `@android:id/text1` or `android.R.id.text1` and I'd like to bind it like `view.text1.setText("bannoe it")`
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you try this:
Just import

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

and you can access your textview like this:

```
text1.setText("bannoe it")
```

Before this you have import cetrain dependencies in gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

I haven't try this,but maybe work this, let me know.

If the above doesnot work, please try this too, that might work.

```
val tv1 = view.bindView<TextView>(android.R.id.text1)
tv1.setText("bannoe it")
```

Happy Coding!!!